# how to set the tab as default in multiple tab using switch case

Tags: android

I'm using *tablayout* for my app. I have to set my middle tab as my opening tab. I'm using 3 tabs in my layout. How can I make it possible?

I'm using *viewpage adapter* and it has switch case for selection of tabs:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    Facebook_Tab tab2;
    Mukil_FM_Tab tab1;
    Shows_List_Tab tab3;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Facebook_Tab tab;
        switch (position) {

            case 1:
                tab2 = new Facebook_Tab();
                return tab2;
            case 0:
                tab1 = new Mukil_FM_Tab();
                return tab1;
            case 2:
                tab3 = new Shows_List_Tab();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like our first mean 0 position will give you this  `Mukil_FM_Tab` tab the middle one , what else you want

Comment: now it shows the middle tab as first tab

Comment: but i want the the middle tab to select as default i.e

Comment: first tab,middle tab,last tab

Comment: did you try with `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(idx);` ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)